# Modify Select Box Text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, select

I have the following select box and I'm trying to modify the All Product Categories text.

```
<select class="postform" id="ofproduct_cat" name="ofproduct_cat">
        <option selected="selected" value="0">All Product Categories</option>
        <option value="28" class="level-0">Los Bengala</option>
        <option value="27" class="level-0">Merchandising</option>
        <option value="29" class="level-0">The Faith Keepers</option>
</select>
```

I'm using the following code:

```
var selectFunction = function() {
     document.getElementById('ofproduct_cat').options[0].text = 'Productos';
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It is linked from the header in a separate file.

Comment: do you execute this function? like `selectFunction()`?

Comment: your code work: http://jsfiddle.net/bsg8b06r/

Comment: Maybe the problem is **when** you're calling `selectFunction()` the code works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## I'm sure, it is function loading problem.

your code is correct only.
Try to load the script in page loading .. Like below code..

```
$(function(){
document.getElementById('ofproduct_cat').options[0].text = 'Productos';
});
```

## Another Way

Create the function:

```
var selectFunction = function() {
 document.getElementById('ofproduct_cat').options[0].text = 'Productos';
}
```

Call the Function:

```
$(function(){
  selectFunction();
 });
```

Because you said linked the file from separate file.

Comment: what if OP not use jQuery? :-)

Comment: It works when I use the second example, or add the first one into footer or header. But why it doesn't work when I just link from a custom.js file? Sorry but I'm pretty bad with JS.

Comment: @Kevin, you should add your html for answer, how you include script files

Comment: @Grundy I include this into header.php: `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/customselect.js"></script>`. It is a WordPress theme.

Comment: @Kevin what inside `customselect.js`?

Comment: @Kevin , At least give your code in fiddle or snippet.. :)

Comment: @vinodh, methinks not easy show wordpress code on jsfiddle :-)

Comment: @Grundy. I too agree.. If we want to understand the loading problem of script, we need to understand the whole script know.. thats why i' m asking ... :)

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys, and thanks for your help. The content is: `var selectFunction = function() {
     document.getElementById('ofproduct_cat').options[0].text = 'Productos';
}`